# How to loop through same file to generate png files in Gnuplot?

Tags: loops, png, gnuplot

I have a huge file named "final.txt" from which I need to generate pm3d plots like

> set pm3d map
>
> set term png
>
> set out "1.png"
>
> spl "final.txt" u 1:2:3 i 1
>
> set out "2.png"
>
> spl "final.txt" u 1:2:3 i 2

and so on till

> set out "1000.png"
> spl "final.txt" u 1:2:3 i 1000

How do I write a loop in Gnuplot to do it for me? It is tiresome to generate 1000 png images manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple `do for` loop. Note, that `index` starts at 0, so in order to plot thousand data sets use

```
set terminal pngcairo
set pm3d map

do for [i=0:999] {
    set output sprintf('%d.png', i)
    splot 'final.text' using 1:2:3 index i
}
```

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for the correction... Smartphones are ideal for writing code ;)